# HighCharts - How to reposition labels after legend is clicked

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to reposition data labels in HighCharts line charts so that they don't overlap.

You can do this initially by attaching a repositioning function to the `load` event:

```
var repositionLabels = function(series) {
    var s1 = series[0].data;
    var s2 = series[1].data;
    var i=0, l=s1.length, higher;

    for(; i<l; i++) {
        higher = s1[i].y > s2[i].y;
        s1[i].dataLabel.attr('y', higher ?  s1[i].dataLabel.y-10 :  s1[i].dataLabel.y+30 );
        s2[i].dataLabel.attr('y', !higher ?  s2[i].dataLabel.y-10 :  s2[i].dataLabel.y+30 );
    }
}
```

For the upper line, data labels are positioned above the line; for the lower line, the data labels are positioned below. So they don't overlap.

### The problem

The problem is that if you click on a legend item to show/hide a line, the data labels revert to their default (bad, overlapping) positions. **Here's a demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/supertrue/QbGPV/984/

I would expect that attaching the same function to the `redraw` event would keep new label positions intact, but it doesn't. Nor does attaching it to `plotOptions.line.events.legendItemClick`.

How can I keep the good label positions intact after legend items are clicked?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the best solution. I delayed the positioning and then it kinda worked.

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/QbGPV/988/)

```
setTimeout(function () {
   positionLabels(chart.series);
}, 500);
```

#### Edit

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/QbGPV/990/)

Comment: Interesting idea. Can you think of a way to hide them at the time of click (and then show them after the animation), so that they don't jump around? `point.attr('display','none')` didn't work, and `point.destroy()` causes a JS error when the line is redrawn. http://jsfiddle.net/supertrue/QbGPV/989/

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the series animation is interfering with the label positioning. If you set:

```
 chart: { renderTo: 'container', type: 'line', animation:false,
```

then it all works fine. I'm guessing that the animation is running after you have positioned the labels, and is re-positioning them for you.

It looks like you'll either have to turn off animation, or use the setTimeout method posted by @anpsmn.

Comment: Yeah, I suspected that. I would love to find a way to keep the animation, though.